# Fazer o <p> se ajustar ao tamanho da imagem

Tags: html, css

Boa noite

Estou colocando uma `<img>` dentro do `<p>` com 192x192 e quando ele possui pouco texto a imagem acaba saindo do `<p>` que ela pertence. Como posso fazer para a borda dele se ajustar com o tamanho da imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código CSS:

```
.retrato
{
float : left;
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
padding-right: 10px;
max-height: auto;
max-width: auto;
}

p
{
text-align: justify;
background-color: #D9E5E3; 
font-size: 20px;
text-align: justify;
padding: 10px 10px;
margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>
        <img class ="retrato" src="../Imagens/PortraitExample.png" alt="Portrait">
        <span class="nomeProdutor">Dilson César Devides</span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Professor, diretor do projeto</strong>. Mestre em Letras - Estudos Literários pela Universidade Federal de Mato Grosso do Sul (2006) e graduado em Letras Português/Espanhol pela Universidade Estadual de Ponta Grossa (2003). Tem experiência na área de Letras, com ênfase em Teoria Literária e Literatura Brasileira, atuando principalmente nos seguintes temas: canção, anos 1970, abertura política, Raul Seixas, cultura de massas, jogos digitais, roteiro para jogos, cibercultura.
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Age of Empires II: The Age of the Kings
    </p>

    <p>
        <img class ="retrato" src="../Imagens/PortraitExample.png" alt="Portrait">
        <span class="nomeProdutor">Fábio 'FABINHO' Dutra</span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Roteirista</strong>. Apaixonado por narrativa em jogos, gosta de ouvir música e jogar.
        <br/>
        <br/> 
        <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Street Fighter
    </p>

    <p>
        <img class ="retrato" src="../Imagens/PortraitExample.png" alt="Portrait">
        <span class="nomeProdutor">José 'JUCA' Américo</span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Desenhista conceitual, game design</strong>. Natural de Bauru, curte tatuagens, música eletrônica, heavy metal, comida japonesa e mangás. Tem interesse em arte em geral.
        <br/>
        <br/> 
        <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Devil May Cry
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta no CSS vc colocar nos estilos do `P` um `overflow:auto`, dessa forma mesmo usando `float` em algum elemento dentro do `P` ele não vai perder a referencia do `height` desse elemento "flutuado"

```css
.retrato {
  float: left;
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #D9E5E3;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="retrato" src="https://unsplash.it/192/192" alt="Portrait">
  <span class="nomeProdutor">Dilson César Devides</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Professor, diretor do projeto</strong>. Mestre em Letras - Estudos Literários pela Universidade Federal de
  Mato Grosso do Sul (2006) e graduado em Letras Português/Espanhol pela Universidade Estadual de Ponta Grossa
  (2003). Tem experiência na área de Letras, com ênfase em Teoria Literária e Literatura Brasileira, atuando
  principalmente nos seguintes temas: canção, anos 1970, abertura política, Raul Seixas, cultura de massas, jogos
  digitais, roteiro para jogos, cibercultura.
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Age of Empires II: The Age of the Kings
</p>

<p>
  <img class="retrato" src="https://unsplash.it/192/192" alt="Portrait">
  <span class="nomeProdutor">Fábio 'FABINHO' Dutra</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Roteirista</strong>. Apaixonado por narrativa em jogos, gosta de ouvir música e jogar.
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Street Fighter
</p>

<p>
  <img class="retrato" src="https://unsplash.it/192/192" alt="Portrait">
  <span class="nomeProdutor">José 'JUCA' Américo</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Desenhista conceitual, game design</strong>. Natural de Bauru, curte tatuagens, música eletrônica, heavy
  metal, comida japonesa e mangás. Tem interesse em arte em geral.
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Devil May Cry
</p>
```

---

Outra técnica seria fazendo um *clearfix* no `<p>`. Assim vc cria no `P` um *pseudo elemento* e nele vc usa um `clear:both`

```
p::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Veja o código abaixo**

```css
.retrato {
  float: left;
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #D9E5E3;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
p::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="retrato" src="https://unsplash.it/192/192" alt="Portrait">
  <span class="nomeProdutor">Dilson César Devides</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Professor, diretor do projeto</strong>. Mestre em Letras - Estudos Literários pela Universidade Federal de
  Mato Grosso do Sul (2006) e graduado em Letras Português/Espanhol pela Universidade Estadual de Ponta Grossa
  (2003). Tem experiência na área de Letras, com ênfase em Teoria Literária e Literatura Brasileira, atuando
  principalmente nos seguintes temas: canção, anos 1970, abertura política, Raul Seixas, cultura de massas, jogos
  digitais, roteiro para jogos, cibercultura.
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Age of Empires II: The Age of the Kings
</p>

<p>
  <img class="retrato" src="https://unsplash.it/192/192" alt="Portrait">
  <span class="nomeProdutor">Fábio 'FABINHO' Dutra</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Roteirista</strong>. Apaixonado por narrativa em jogos, gosta de ouvir música e jogar.
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Street Fighter
</p>

<p>
  <img class="retrato" src="https://unsplash.it/192/192" alt="Portrait">
  <span class="nomeProdutor">José 'JUCA' Américo</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Desenhista conceitual, game design</strong>. Natural de Bauru, curte tatuagens, música eletrônica, heavy
  metal, comida japonesa e mangás. Tem interesse em arte em geral.
  <br />
  <br />
  <strong>Jogo Favorito:</strong> Devil May Cry
</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado por ter me ajudado e pelas informações a mais ^^

Comment: @Tecnolog disponha meu amigo, precisando é só perguntar!